# Simple regex replace to keep original string

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, string, replace

I have this:

```
Title = Regex.Replace(Title, s, "<span style=\"background:yellow\">" + s + "</span>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Where `s` is a word like `facebook`.  If the title is:

```
How to make a Facebook game
```

I would like to replaced to:

```
How to make a <span style="background:yellow">Facebook</span> game
```

Even if the search word is 'facebook' (note capitalisation).  Basically, how do I retain the original capitalisation of the word?

Another example, search term `FACEBOOK`, string `Hello FaCeBoOk` is turned to `Hello <span style="background:yellow">FaCeBoOk</span>`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `$&` [substitution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx) for that:

```
Regex.Replace(Title, s, "<span style=\"background:yellow\">$&</span>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var input = "How to make a Facebook game, do you like facebook?";
var searchFor = "facebook";
var result = Regex.Replace(
    input, 
    searchFor, 
    "<span style=\"background:yellow\">$+</span>", 
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

The only important thing is the `$+`. It contains the last acquired text. This will work even for "How to make a Facebook game, do you like facebook?" The first Facebook will be left upper-case, the second one will be left lower-case.

I'll add that if you want to look only for whole words, then you can make:

```
searchFor = @"\b" + searchFor + @"\b";
```

This will look only for strings that are on word boundary.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply include a capture group that matches the word "facebook", and include that capture group as part of the replacement string. This will end up including it in the end result exactly as it appeared in the input.

```
var title = "How to make a Facebook game";
title = Regex.Replace(title,
                      "(facebook)",
                      "<span style=\"background:yellow\">$1</span>",
                      RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/8Zn1W)**.