# How can I use the $+ or $& regular expressions in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I've been searching for a while trying to figure out why this wont work- I found the exact thing I want to accomplish [Simple regex replace to keep original string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379972/simple-regex-replace-to-keep-original-string) but  I can't seem to use the regular expression `$+` or `$&` in Java
like so:

```
String S1 = "bob";
String S2 = "the builder";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(S1, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(ST);
ST = m.replaceAll("$+/"+S2);
```

Comment: `$` is a special character and means `end of line`. You need to escape it. Also, what is `ST`? This variable was created after you tried to call it.

Comment: ST is the long string that represents the document it was created beforehand - I just want to accomplish the same thing as in the link- how do I do that in java? escaping the $ doesn't seem to work

Comment: Terminology tip: A "regular expression" is used for matching.  Replacement strings (used in `replaceAll`) can have special character sequences like $0 or ${group}, but they're not called "regular expressions".  I don't know of a special name for them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `$0` to refer to the whole match in replacement pattern.