# How to replace a string using the original matched value

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to Highlight a string by wrapping a `<span class="highlight"></span>` in the searched string.

made a simple Extension Method as:

```
public static string Highlight(this string source, string highlightString)
{
    var regex = new Regex(highlightString, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    var r = regex.Replace(
                source, 
                "<span class=\"highlight\">" + highlightString + "</span>");

    return r;
}
```

works fine but what I really trying to do is apply the wrapping in the original match.

as is, if I search for <kbd>trip</kbd> I get the result of

```
<span class="highlight">trip</span> Nordic
```

and what I really want, is to have

```
<span class="highlight">Trip</span> Nordic
```

as the original string is `Trip Nordic`

how can I replace the original part of the string that it's matched and not the string I'm searching for?

the bugger is that `regex` has no property that tells me what was found (as original string), not even the position where it found the match...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple regex replace to keep original string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379972/simple-regex-replace-to-keep-original-string)

Comment: directly stringObj.Replace wont work? Just a thought...

Comment: Using substitutions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use [substitution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx):

```
public static string Highlight(this string source, string highlightString)
{
    var regex = new Regex(highlightString, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    var r = regex.Replace(
            source, 
            "<span class=\"highlight\">$&</span>");
}
```

Output:

```
<span class="highlight">Trip</span> Nordic
```

Answer (score 1):

```
regex.Replace(
            source, 
            "<span class=\"highlight\">$0</span>");
```

should work too.

$0 = group zero = whole match